# Maxscale: combine readwritesplit and schemarouter

Tags: mariadb, sharding, maxscale

I'm trying to setup maxscale to use schemarouter and readwritesplit.
I have many shards for my mysql database. Each shard has a slave
So the idea is to use one schemarouter on masters and one on slaves to proxy all shards. Then use These 2 services in readwritesplit.

```
This cause the following issue:
2017-02-10 14:57:48   error  : Failure loading users data from backend [10.161.66.145:4009] for service [Splitter Service]. MySQL error 2013, Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: waiting for inital communication packet', system error: 110
2017-02-10 14:57:52   error  : Failure loading users data from backend [10.161.66.145:4008] for service [Splitter Service]. MySQL error 2013, Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 110
2017-02-10 14:57:52   error  : Unable to get user data from backend database for service [Splitter Service]. Failed to connect to any of the backend databases.
```

Any help would be nice.

My schemarouter are both working fine.
Here is the readwritesplit config:

```
[max_ro]
type=server
address=10.10.10.10
port=4009
protocol=MySQLBackend

[max_rw]
type=server
address=10.10.10.10
port=4008
protocol=MySQLBackend

[Splitter Service]
type=service
router=readwritesplit
servers=max_ro,max_rw
user=maxscale
passwd=maxscale

[Splitter Listener]
type=listener
service=Splitter Service
protocol=MySQLClient
port=4010
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The errors are most likely caused by the fact that the readwritesplit services have not yet started. There is a bug report about this behavior on the [MariaDB Jira](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-1167).

If the sharding service works and no more errors are logged once MaxScale has started then everything is working as expected and the errors can be ignored as is described in [this bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-1028?focusedCommentId=88859&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-88859).

Another way to solve this problem would be to separate the configuration into two parts and use separate MaxScale instances; one for the sharding service and another one for the read-write splitting service. This does add an extra layer of complexity as two services need to be started instead of one.